# backbone.js this.el not fetched/selected on dynamically loaded views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am having a problem with dynamically loaded views not being able to attach to the `this.el` scope variable.

To illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

**HTML PAGE**

```
<html>
    <head> head stuff </head>
    <body>
          <div id="appWrap"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now if I had a view called View.PageSetUp that will add a couple of set up divs to #appWrap I get:

**HTML PAGE - View.AppSetUp**

```
<html>
    <head> head stuff </head>
    <body>
          <div id="appWrap">
                <div id="nav">buttons…</div>
                <div id="side">side stuff…</div>
                <div id="content"></div>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problems come when I want to add a specific view to the content stage because `this.el` will not see the dynamically loaded `$('#content')`.

Trying to then reload the this.el in the initialize function turned out to be a BIG no no… it didn't like it.

```
this.el = $('#content'); // rubbish idea!
```

It feels like dynamically loaded templates and views must be viable in a javascript application, so how would I make this work?

I guess one possibility is that when I am loading my scripts the el is set up then and there:

```
App.Views.Channel = Backbone.View.extend({
      ………………
})
```

Should I be using a loader to make this work? If so, any recommendations? I have experience with required but would it be too much for something so simple?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked out the solution to this, so I'll leave it here incase anyone else has the same problem.

Basically I was setting `el` in the view itself:

```
App.Views.Channel = Backbone.View.extend({
  el : $('#myID'),
  ………………
})
```

Where I should have set it when I called a new instance of the view.

```
newView = App.Views.Channel(model, { el: $("#search_container") });
```

All seems to work anyway!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for when setting el when creating a view. Ex: @player_view = new app.PlayerView({model: player, el: $("#player_score") })

Answer (score 1):

You can set `el` in the view itself, but do it with tagName, className and id. Something like this:

```
App.Nav.View = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "div",
  id: "nav",
  render: function() {
    /* Nav buttons */
  }
});

App.View = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("#appWrap"),
  initialize: function() {
    var appNavView = new App.Nav.View;
    $(this.el).append(appNavView.render().el);
  }  
});

appView = new App.View;
```